# drupal site on working on apache

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7

my apache2 error.log shows:

```
[Sun Nov 10 18:40:46 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 with 
Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 10 18:41:13 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: 
/home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/pw/js, referer: http://pw/
[Sun Nov 10 18:41:22 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist:  
/home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/pw/node, referer: http://pw/

[Sun Nov 10 18:43:27 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Nov 10 18:43:28 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 with  
Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 10 18:46:47 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist:   
/home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/pw/js, referer: http://pw/

[Sun Nov 10 18:46:50 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist:   
/home/vishal/Dropbox/sites/pw/user, referer: http://pw/
```

---

Here is my details of the default http://pastebin.com/sWFDN5Yr

the confusing thing is that other sites work but only the vhost for pw
gives error. The main page comes up however the inner pages does not come up.

Thank you,
Vishal

Comment: nevermind I solved it. it was a clean url problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its most likely a problem with ur clean url. 
type `http://yoursite?q=user/login` and see if ur login page comes up, if so its a issue with ur vhost entry is not set to allow redirect and clean urls